# Proper initialization of sys.path when main script is in a submodule

Tags: python, module, path, python-import

The first entry of `sys.path` is the directory of the current script, according to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path). In the following setup, I would like to change this default. Imagine the following directory structure:

```
src/
    core/
        stuff/
        tools/
            tool1.py
            tool2.py
    gui/
        morestuff/
        gui.py
```

The scripts `tool*.py` and `gui.py` are intended to be run as scripts, like the following:

```
python src/core/tools/tool2.py
python src/gui/gui.py
```

Now all tools import from `src.core.stuff`, and the GUI needs `gui.morestuff`. This means that `sys.path[0]` should point to `src/`, but it points to `src/core/tools/` or `src/gui/` by default.

I can adjust `sys.path[0]` in every script (with a construct like the following, e.g., at the beginning of `gui.py`):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.path[0]: sys.path[0] = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.path[0]))
```

However, this is sort of redundant, and it becomes tedious for a mature code base with thousands of scripts. I also know the `-m` switch:

```
python -m gui.gui
```

But this requires the current directory to be `src/`.

Is there a better way to achieve the desired result, e.g. by modifying the `__init__.py` files?

**EDIT**: This is for Python 2.7:

```
~$ python -V
Python 2.7.3
```

Comment: For starters there's `python -m core.tools.tool1`

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: @Kos: Thanks for reading the entire post.

Comment: @krlmlr (*cleans the glasses*) :)

Comment: you could use `setup.py` to define `entry_points` e.g., `entry_points={'console_scripts': ['my-tool=my.core.tools.tool2:main', 'my-gui=my.gui.gui:main']}` (assuming the top-level package is called `my` and the functionality is in `main()` functions) It defines `my-tool` and `my-gui` scripts.

Comment: see also links in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14186074/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got three basic options here. I've been through all three in both a production environment and personal projects. In many ways they build on each other. However, my advice is to just skip to the last one.

The fundamental problem is that you need your `./src` directory to be in the python search path. This is really what python packaging is all about.

**PYTHONPATH**

The most straightforward, user defined way to adjust your python path is through the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`. You can set it at run time, doing something like:

```
PYTHONPATH=/src python src/gui/gui.py
```

You can of course also set this up in your global environment so hopefully all processes that need it will find the correct `PYTHONPATH`. But, just remember, you'll always forget one. Usually at 3 AM when your `cron` task finally runs.

**Site Packages**

To avoid needing an environment variable, your options are pretty much to include your software in an existing entry in the source path, or find some additional way to add a new search path. So this can mean dropping the contents of your `src` directory into `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` or wherever your system `site-packages` is located.

Since you may not want to actually include the code in site-packages, you can create a symlink for your two sub-packages.

This is of course less than ideal for a number of reasons. If you're not careful with naming then suddenly every python program on the machine is exposed to potential name conflicts. You're exposing your software to every user on the machine. You might run into issues if python get's updated. If you add a new sub-package, now you have to create a new symlink.

A slightly better approach is to include a `.pth` file somewhere in your site-packages. When python encounters these files, it adds the contents (which is supposed to be the name of a directory) to the search path. This avoids the problem of having to remember to add a new symlink for each new sub-package.

**virtualenv and packaging**

The best solution is to just bite the bullet and do real python packaging. This, combined with great tools like [virtualenv and pip](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) let you have an isolated (or semi-isolated) python environment.

Under virtualenv, you would have a custom `site-packages` for just your project where you can easily install your software into it, avoiding all the problems of the earlier solutions. virtualenv also makes it easy to maintain executable scripts so that the python environment it runs under is exactly as you expect.

The one downside is that you have to write and maintain a `setup.py` which will instruct `pip` (the python installer) to include your software in the virtualenv. The contents would be something like:

```
!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from distutils.core import setup


setup(
    name='myproject',
    package_dir={'myproject': 'src'},
    scripts=['src/gui/gui.py', 'src/core/tools/tool1.py', 'src/core/tools/tool2.py']
)
```

So, to setup this environment, it's going to look something like this:

```
virtualenv env
env/bin/pip install -e setup.py
```

To run your script, then you'd just do something like:

```
env/bin/tool1.py
```

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. Unfortunately, packaging is not an option, the software is under development in a SVN working copy. However, I was wondering if I could also use the second approach with my SVN working copy in connection with virtualenv: Place an appropriately formatted `.pth` file into the `lib/python2.X/site-packages` subdirectory of the virtual environment. Any thoughts?

Comment: Wouldn't the third option provide what you need? Installing a package with `pip install -e` installs the package with its scripts, linking to your development code (rather than installing a copy), so any edits to the code in the repo would automatically be available in the virtualenv.

Comment: Placing an appropriate .pth file into virtualenv is essentially what `pip install -e` does for you (as per Josh's response) It also writes place holders into your bin directory that links it to the appropriate instance of python.

Comment: Will give the third option a try. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

The *only* officially approved way to run a script that is in a package is by using the `-m` flag. While you could run a script directly and try to do `sys.path` manipulations yourself in each script, it's likely to be a big pain. If you move a script between folders, the logic for rewriting `sys.path` may also need to be changed to reflect the new location. Even if you get `sys.path` right, explicit relative imports will not work correctly.

Now, making `python -m mypackage.mymodule` work requires that either you be in the project's top level folder (`src` in your case), or for that top level folder to be on the Python search path. Requiring you to be in a specific folder is awkward, and you've said that you don't want that. Getting `src` into the search path is our goal then.

I think the best approach is to use the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to point the interpreter to your project's `src` folder so that it can find your packages from anywhere.

This solution is simple to set up (the environment variable can be be set automatically in your `.profile`, `.bashrc` or some other equivalent place), and will work for any number of scripts. If you move your project, just update your environment settings and you'll be all set, without needing to do any more work for each script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wanted to do this to avoid having to set `PYTHONPATH` in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to do this to avoid having to set PYTHONPATH in the first place

There are other places you can hook into Python's `sys.path` initialization, using the [`site`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) module, which is (by default) automatically imported when Python initializes.

Based on the this code in `site.py`...

```
# Prefixes for site-packages; add additional prefixes like /usr/local here
PREFIXES = [sys.prefix, sys.exec_prefix]
```

...it looks as if the intention was that this file was designed to be modified after installation, which is one option, although it also provides other ways you can influence `sys.path`, e.g. by placing a `.pth` file somewhere inside your `site-packages` directory.

Assuming the desired result is to make the code work 'out of the box', this would work, but only for all users on a single system.

If you need it to work on multiple systems, then you'd have to apply the same changes to all systems.

For deployment, this is no big deal. Indeed, many Python packages already do something like this. e.g. on Ubuntu...

```
~$ dpkg -L python-imaging | grep pth
/usr/share/pyshared/PIL.pth
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL.pth
```

...but if your intention is to make it easy for multiple concurrent developers, each using their own system, you may be better off sticking with the current option of adding some 'boilerplate' code to every Python module which is intended to be run as a script.

There may be another option, but it depends on exactly what you're trying to achieve.