# Jython does not catch Exceptions

Tags: python, exception, import, jython

Jython doesn't have the `-m` option, and it raises an error with `from .utils import *`.

The solution is not to use relative path

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
from utils import *
```

As I need to use the code both Jython and CPython, I came up with this command:

```
try:
    from .utils import *
except Exception: # Jython or Python with python context/context.py invocation
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
    from utils import *
```

However, Jython doesn't seem to catch the exception, and still generates an exception.

```
  File "context/context.py", line 9
SyntaxError: 'import *' not allowed with 'from .'
```

Based on [How to know that the interpreter is Jython or CPython in the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305438/how-to-know-that-the-interpreter-is-jython-or-cpython-in-the-code), I tried

```
binary = sys.executable
if binary is None:
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
    from utils import *
else:
    from .utils import *
```

I still get the `SyntaxError`, why Jython interpreter keeps parsing `from .utils import *` when it was supposed to do so; I mean, this code works.

```
binary = sys.executable
if binary is None:
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
    from utils import *
else:
    pass
```

This is my Jython information:

```
Jython 2.7b1 (default:ac42d59644e9, Feb 9 2013, 15:24:52) 
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)] on java1.7.0_51
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: witch Jython version are you using? Depending on the version relative imports are not allowed

Comment: unrelated: there could be some [`import` issues if you name your package and a module within the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183541/why-python-finds-module-instead-of-package-if-they-have-the-same-name), don't: `xyz/xyz.py` if `xyz` is a package.

Comment: unrelated: do not add a directory *inside* a package to `sys.path`. It makes all the modules in the package available under two names (all modules became top-level modules). It may cause hard to debug issues with the imports and the global state.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it doesn't like your relative import, I am thinking about 2 possibles solutions:

- Try to import the `utils` package from the root of your project.
- Add the path to `utils` package to your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I have an easy way to solve the relative import, the real issue is that Jython keep parsing the code that was not supposed to do. I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

`issubclass(SyntaxError, Exception)` says that it should be caught and indeed, if you raise it manually it is being caught:

```
try:
   raise SyntaxError
except Exception:
   print('caught it')
```

It prints `caught it`. Though

```
try:
     from . import *
except Exception:
     print('nope')
```

leads to:

```
 File "<stdin>", line 2
SyntaxError: 'import *' not allowed with 'from .'
```

If you add some code above then you see that it is not executed i.e., the latter exception is not runtime. It is the same in CPython e.g.:

```
import sys
sys.stderr.write("you won't see it\n")

try:
    1_ # cause SyntaxError at compile time
except:
    print("you won't see it either")
```

The error is raised during compilation.

To workaround the problem, you could try to use absolute imports:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from context.utils import * # both Jython and CPython
```