# How to know that the interpreter is Jython or CPython in the code?

Tags: python, jython

Is there a way to detect that the interpreter that executes the code is Jython or CPython?

I have another post: [Jython does not catch Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305365/jython-does-not-catch-exceptions). For this case, if I know the interpreter is Jython, I can have different code that should work.

```
if JYTHON:
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
    from utils import *
else:
    from .utils import *
```

Comment: Python is the language specification. The most well known implementations are Jython and **CPython**.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik: So, is your point that there is no (easy or programatic) way?

Comment: No no; I'm was pointing out that the interpreter is Jython or CPython, not Jython or Python. I think the edit makes it clear.

Comment: Is the Jython executable named ```jython.exe``` or is it just ```python.exe```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/python-what-os-am-i-running-on

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**There is an official way to do it!** :-) Please have a look at

http://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html#platform.python_implementation

> Returns a string identifying the Python implementation. Possible return values are: ‘CPython’, ‘IronPython’, ‘Jython’, ‘PyPy’.
>
> New in version 2.6.

I did not know that before.

**Old answer**:

There probably is no standardized interface, but you can use some educated guessing, based on e.g. `sys.executable` (http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.executable), and `sys.version`. Furthermore, some interpreters for sure provide features that are specific to them, which you can make use of.

Comment: Note: starting from python3.3 there's also [`sys.implementation`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sys.html#sys.implementation) which contains the name and version of the implementation and might contain other relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is safe way, but I got a hint from [Find full path of the Python interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589711/find-full-path-of-python-interpreter).

With `print sys.executable`, I have different results.

```
context> jython context/context.py
None
context> python context/context.py
/usr/bin/python
```

So, checking `sys.executable` might be one way for the checking.